# Which files constitute a "program" in Java?

Tags: java, class

For a course in my university, we are supposed to write three sorting programs, then archive them into a .tar file and send to the teacher. I have written these programs and now I'm unsure if I should archive the .class files, the .java files, or both (the instructions specify that I should send "three files", but maybe it does not mean much since they recommend that you program in python). I don't really understand why there are both .java and .class files, can anyone explain to me?

Comment: You should send the java files because code is readabale in those files. Your professor need to see your code and not the compiled class file.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/intro/definition.html

Comment: @JunedAhsan: That is actually the answer. Why did you post it as comment?

Comment: @AaronDigulla Moved to answer lets see if people accept it ;-)

Comment: @JunedAhsan I certainly upvoted it

Comment: Without any more info I'd recommend sending both the .java and .class files.  He can ignore the .class files if he wishes, and he almost certainly wants to see the .java files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should send the java files because code is readabale in those files. Your professor need to see and access your code and not the compiled class file.

Comment: Yes, and to elaborate, your professor will likely check your source (.java file) against previously submitted examples to ensure you didn't copy/steal, and then the professor will probably compile your code and test it. So all the professor needs is the source files (.java)

Answer (score 2):

`.java` files are human readable and `.class` are machine readable. So you need to send both. The `.java` should be evaluated, but I would directly run the program in the .class file than bother going through the buggy code. Check if the program works and then check for code quality in the source files.

Answer (score 2):

Send both sets; .class for the computer to execute, .java for the professor to read.

It is possible, by the way, to decompile .class and recover the .java. (see jd.exe on windows) But, as well as the program comments, all the syntatic sugar - enums, generics (due to type erasure) - will no longer be there.

Comment: for homework, we shouldn't be recommending decompiling the professor's examples... this will get the OP into trouble...

Comment: Thanks for your help. @Snakedoc, the professor has not given any examples and I would never steal his code anyway. Does asking a basic question automatically imply that I plagiarize? The replies in this thread are astonishing.

Comment: @Sid I wasn't directing that at you, but more of a "general advice". I'd hope a learning programmer wouldn't plagiarizer, otherwise you'd never learn! ;-P